# How to get "Verification Tab Data" in TFS WorkItem using C#?

Tags: c#, tfs

I want to fetch the data in one of the WorkItems. I am getting the Description, Created By and all Information (left side only), But I didn't get the right page data Like - Clarification, Planning, Validation and all.

This is the code I am using to get the WorkItem,

```
WorkItemCollection qryRslts = workItemStore.Query("Select * From WorkItems Where ID = '0000007' ");
```

Any documents or link related to this will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Use `workItemStore.OpenWorkItem(7)` to get an instance of the WorkItem and fetch the fields from there.

Comment: Which kind of workitem type you want to get? Could you give a screenshot of  the ''Verification Tab Data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try the code below:

```
WorkItemCollection qryRslts = workItemStore.Query("Select * From WorkItems Where ID = '0000007' ");
foreach (WorkItem workItem in qryRslts)
{
    workItem.Open();
    workItem.Fields["filed name"].Value = "***";
    workItem.Save();
}
```

If you only want to get one workitem, it's unnecessary to use a query. You could use `workItemStore.GetWorkItem(Id)` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb140391(v=vs.120).aspx) to get [WorkItem class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem(v=vs.120).aspx).